# Is every graph a generalized strict unit distance graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

A strict unit-distance graph is a graph which can be constructed from a collection of points in the Euclidean plane by connecting pairs of vertices with edges if and only if they have unit distance. My generalization of this concept removes the 2D requirement, allowing Euclidean space of any finite number of dimensions. Is every finite graph isomorphic to a generalized strict unit-distance graph?

Comment: Yes, the wikipedia article gives a reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph#Generalization_to_higher_dimensions

Comment: Without bounding the dimension this is rather clear: the distances between $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ may be arbitrary numbers close enough to 1. So, you may make those of them which you need equal to $1$, and others $1+\varepsilon_n$, say